# xslt: select unique node via intermediate reference node?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

XSLT 2.

Hi, I have an xml that has 3 nodes, named from point of view of the 'children' called:  Children, Fathers and MothersFathers.  Starting with the Fathers node I need to find the a childs MothersFather node based on the ID's in the Child nodes (the Child node is the intermediate reference joining the other two.)

So, for each Father get his children's **distinct** MothersFather  - these aren't humans, a father could have hundreds of children but only twenty or so of the related  MothersFathers :)

Simplified version of XML (in real life have about 80 Father nodes, 3000 Child nodes and 400 MothersFather nodes):

```
<t>
<Children>
    <Child>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <FathersID>100</FathersID>
        <MothersFatherID>200</MothersFatherID>    
    </Child>
    <Child>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <FathersID>100</FathersID>
        <MothersFatherID>201</MothersFatherID>    
    </Child>
    <Child>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <FathersID>100</FathersID>
        <MothersFatherID>202</MothersFatherID>    
    </Child>
    <Child>
        <ID>4</ID>
        <FathersID>100</FathersID>
        <MothersFatherID>201</MothersFatherID>    
    </Child>
    <Child>
        <ID>5</ID>
        <FathersID>101</FathersID>
        <MothersFatherID>201</MothersFatherID>    
    </Child>
</Children>
<Fathers>
    <Father>
        <ID>100</ID>
    </Father>
    <Father>
        <ID>101</ID>
    </Father>
</Fathers>
<MothersFathers>
    <MothersFather>
        <ID>200</ID>
    </MothersFather>
    <MothersFather>
        <ID>201</ID>
    </MothersFather>
    <MothersFather>
        <ID>202</ID>
    </MothersFather>
</MothersFathers>        
</t>
```

My xslt looks like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kFathersChildren" match="Child" use="FathersID"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Fathers"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Fathers">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Father"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Father">
        <xsl:text>&#10;FATHER: ID=</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
        <!-- Now show all this fathers childrens maternal grandfathers based on the ID in the Child node -->

        <!--TRY 1: this works, as in gets the right nodes, but doesn't do distinct values....--> 
        <xsl:for-each select="key('kFathersChildren', ID)">  <!-- get the fathers children --> 
            <xsl:text>&#10; found child: current MFid=</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="current()/MothersFatherID"/>
            <xsl:text> ID=</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//MothersFathers/MothersFather[ID=current()/MothersFatherID]"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <!-- *** THIS IS WHERE I GET LOST??? - Do the same thing but only get distinct MothersFatherID's... -->

        <!--TRY 2: note- won't compile in current state... -->
        <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(key('kFathersChildren', ID)[MothersFatherID])">  
            <xsl:text>&#10;  Distinct MothersFatherID ???? - don't know what to select </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//MothersFathers/MothersFather[ID=??????????"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//MothersFathers/MothersFather">
        <xsl:text>&#10;      IN MothersFather template... ID=</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In Try 1 I can get all the nodes and MothersFatherID's. The output of Try1 is:

```
FATHER: ID=100
 found child: current MFid=200 ID=1
      IN MothersFather template... ID=200
 found child: current MFid=201 ID=2
      IN MothersFather template... ID=201
 found child: current MFid=202 ID=3
      IN MothersFather template... ID=202
 found child: current MFid=201 ID=4
      IN MothersFather template... ID=201
FATHER: ID=101
 found child: current MFid=201 ID=5
      IN MothersFather template... ID=201
```

In Try2 where I'm selecting 'distinct-value' I would like output like:

```
FATHER: ID=100
      IN MothersFather template... ID=201
      IN MothersFather template... ID=200
      IN MothersFather template... ID=202
FATHER: ID=101
      IN MothersFather template... ID=201
```

(is not real output - just debug stuff showing I can reference the right nodes).

BUT I can't figure out what I'm meant to use to reference the unique MothersFatherID to pass to the 'apply-templates' call.

No matter what I've tried I get variations on errors like:
`Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:anyAtomicType` or `Axis step child::element('':MothersFatherID) cannot be used here: the context item is an atomic value`.   I think they mean I'm trying to select nodes where a string value is used or vice-versa....  maybe my use of distinct-value() function is altogether wrong?

Can anyone shed some light on how to do this please?  (I keep hoping this xslt will have some zen moment of enlightenment when I won't get stuck on this sort of thing).

Additionally, once I have that going I'm going to want the MothersFather in a sorted order for each Father - in real xml there is a 'Name' associated with each 'ID' - hopefully the for-each 'sort' statement will be similar reference to what fixes above problem?

Thanks for your time.
Bryce.

**EDIT:**

Wow!! Thank you for your answer Dimitre. I have gone over it and was hoping you might be able to break it down a bit for me as I don't fully grok it?
The answer was:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kMFByFId" match="MothersFatherID"
          use="../FathersID"/>

 <xsl:key name="kMFById" match="MothersFather" use="ID"/>

 <xsl:key name="ChildByFIdAndMFId" match="Child"
  use="concat(FathersID, '+', MothersFatherID)"/>

 <xsl:template match="Children|MothersFathers|text()"/>

 <xsl:template match="Father">
   Father ID=<xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "key('kMFById',
         key('kMFByFId', ID)
          [generate-id(..)
          =
           generate-id(key('ChildByFIdAndMFId',
                            concat(../FathersID,'+',.)
                          )[1]
                       )
          ]
        )">
     <xsl:sort select="ID" data-type="number"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="MothersFather">
      MothersFather ID=<xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the use of the keys involved.

The line `<xsl:template match="Children|MothersFathers|text()"/>` - how is this line doing its thing?  If I step it through a debugger it just jumps straight past this line. If I comment it out there is lots of superfluous output that I can't see the source of.

And the apply-templates line that gives the MothersFather node `<xsl:apply-templates select= "key('kMFById', key('kMFByFId', ID)[generate-id(..)  =

generate-id(key('ChildByFIdAndMFId', concat(../FathersID,'+',.))[1] ) ] )">`   - I've been trying to break this down on paper to see the magic but not quite getting it.
It is something like  `key('kMFById', key('kMFByFId', ID)` means get the matching MothersFather nodes by the current Father ID where `[generate-id(..)` the generated id of '(dot dot)' - something to do with a parent node? which one? equals the generated id based on ChildByFIdAndMFId key `[1]` - does this 1 get only the first occurrence of the matching generated id's thereby giving my distinct value?

(This answer by Dimitre is also very similar to JLRishie's answer. His sort appears to work, am I missing something there Dimitre?)

Regards, Bryce.

Comment: user1840734, Is JLRishe's solution sorting correctly? Yes, it is sorting correctly *now*. But it wasn't sorting correctly two days ago when I posted my answer. Since then he edited his answer twice and has fixed the sorting bug. As for "This answer by Dimitre is also very similar to JLRishie's answer", I would say that they are/were essentially different in that my solution worked correctly from the very start, while JLRishe's sorting was incorrect.  Unlike others I always test my solutions. Another difference is in shortness and readability -- in both these my solution is obviously better.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I'm not sure why you keep saying your answer is shorter. Mine is 23 lines (originally 20) and yours is 34.  Perhaps yours has 10 or 15 fewer displayable characters and you moved some text over to the left, but that's hardly something worth boasting about. You imply that I didn't test my answer, but I did - the output in my original post was the actual output, and matched the question's requested output. It's true that I didn't sufficiently think ahead about being able to sort on a separate field, but that is an oversight I will not make again.

Comment: @JLRishe, Why, isnt this obvious? Your transformation occupies very long lines that make it unreadable -- I am sure you could put the entire transformation on a single line... When I format your transformation in the same way mine is formatted -- to make it readable, it occupies not 23 lines, but 37 lines. And, as we know, 37 > 34. If I used your "formatting style, which I never will, my answer would be just 19 lines of code.  Unless you stop producing unreadable answers, they would be worthless to the readers, despite the real value I believe these answers have -- just due to formatting.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I guess you and I have different concepts of what constitutes "unreadable" and "worthless". In an ordinary code editor, the lines in my response are entirely displayable and well within the realm of readability (IMHO). Nonetheless, I will make a continued effort to ensure that my lines are not too long in the future.

Comment: @JLRishe, It isn't true that "In an ordinary code editor, the lines in my response are entirely displayable and well within the realm of readability". I am using an XSLT IDE (ordinary editor part of it) and even allocating the whole screen to it, a significant part of the code needs scrolling to the right in order to be displayed. Scrolling to the right, however, makes invisible the left-most part of the code. Your code goes as far as 147 positions to the right -- this by no means is "entirely displayable and well within the realm of readability". I welcome your resolution to improve this.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev All fixed now. I guess your screen is quite a bit smaller than the one I'm using.  On my 19" screen at 1920x1200 resolution, even that 147 character line only occupied 2/3 of the screen's width. I regularly have to inspect XSLT that's as much as 300 characters wide, so 147 isn't very much for me.

Comment: @JLRishe, I can see all the code now without scrolling -- a good first step. However the code is still not quite readable -- you could use empty lines and vertical alignment to achieve better readability. This is especially useful for newbie XSLT programmers but even expert programmers do frown when they see 4 brackets and three square brackets on the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation -- shorter and well formatted and readable without horizontal/vertical scrolling. Also, it applies sorting correctly, unlike other answers**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kMFByFId" match="MothersFatherID"
          use="../FathersID"/>

 <xsl:key name="kMFById" match="MothersFather" use="ID"/>

 <xsl:key name="ChildByFIdAndMFId" match="Child"
  use="concat(FathersID, '+', MothersFatherID)"/>

 <xsl:template match="Children|MothersFathers|text()"/>

 <xsl:template match="Father">
   Father ID=<xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "key('kMFById',
         key('kMFByFId', ID)
          [generate-id(..)
          =
           generate-id(key('ChildByFIdAndMFId',
                            concat(../FathersID,'+',.)
                          )[1]
                       )
          ]
        )">
     <xsl:sort select="ID" data-type="number"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="MothersFather">
      MothersFather ID=<xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document (the provided, but a little shuffled to test for correct sorting):**

```
<t>
<Children>
    <Child>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <FathersID>100</FathersID>
        <MothersFatherID>201</MothersFatherID>
    </Child>
    <Child>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <FathersID>100</FathersID>
        <MothersFatherID>200</MothersFatherID>
    </Child>
    <Child>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <FathersID>100</FathersID>
        <MothersFatherID>202</MothersFatherID>
    </Child>
    <Child>
        <ID>4</ID>
        <FathersID>100</FathersID>
        <MothersFatherID>201</MothersFatherID>
    </Child>
    <Child>
        <ID>5</ID>
        <FathersID>101</FathersID>
        <MothersFatherID>201</MothersFatherID>
    </Child>
</Children>
<Fathers>
    <Father>
        <ID>100</ID>
    </Father>
    <Father>
        <ID>101</ID>
    </Father>
</Fathers>
<MothersFathers>
    <MothersFather>
        <ID>200</ID>
    </MothersFather>
    <MothersFather>
        <ID>201</ID>
    </MothersFather>
    <MothersFather>
        <ID>202</ID>
    </MothersFather>
</MothersFathers>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
   Father ID=100
      MothersFather ID=200
      MothersFather ID=201
      MothersFather ID=202
   Father ID=101
      MothersFather ID=201
```

**Do note**:

The transformation is executed correctly both with an XSLT 1.0 and with XSLT 2.0 processor.

---

**Update**:

The OP has edited the question, asking some questions about this solution:

I get the use of the keys involved.

> The line `<xsl:template match="Children|MothersFathers|text()"/>` -
>   how is this line doing its thing? If I step it through a debugger it
>   just jumps straight past this line. If I comment it out there is lots
>   of superfluous output that I can't see the source of.

You have discovered what this template with empty body is doing -- it prevents the superfluous output from being written. The XSLT processor has a number of built-in templates that are selected for execution when processing a given node -- in case the XSLT transformation doesn't specify a template matching this node.

The built-in template for any element outputs the concatenation of the string values of all of its text-node-descendants -- and this is exactly what you see as superfluous output.

To avoid this, I have provided a template matching thode elements. This overrides (suppresses) the built-in template. As this tamplate has no body, no output is produced.

> And the apply-templates line that gives the `MothersFather` node
>   `<xsl:apply-templates select= "key('kMFById', key('kMFByFId',`
>   `ID)[generate-id(..) =  generate-id(key('ChildByFIdAndMFId',`
>   `concat(../FathersID,'+',.))[1] ) ] )">` - I've been trying to break
>   this down on paper to see the magic but not quite getting it. It is
>   something like `key('kMFById', key('kMFByFId', ID)` means get the
>   matching `MothersFather` nodes by the current `Father ID` where
>   `[generate-id(..) the generated id of '(dot dot)'` - something to do
>   with a parent node? which one? equals the generated id based on
>   `ChildByFIdAndMFId key [1]` - does this `1` get only the first occurrence
>   of the matching generated id's thereby giving my distinct value?

Your question is about this code fragment:

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "key('kMFById',
         key('kMFByFId', ID)
          [generate-id(..)
          =
           generate-id(key('ChildByFIdAndMFId',
                            concat(../FathersID,'+',.)
                          )[1]
                       )
          ]
        )">
     <xsl:sort select="ID" data-type="number"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
```

In order to understand what is going on here, you need to get acquainted with the **[Muenchian Grouping Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.

**What essentially the above code fragment is saying is**:

process all `MothersFather` elements that are the first such element that is a sibling of a `FathersID` that has the same value as the `ID` of the current (`Father`) node.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, I've edited the question above trying to understand your answer better.  Sorry for the bad formatting, I was doing my editing on a small screen and just assumed the pane would expand bigger on a larger screen - I see it doesn't. I'll try to watch  it in future so as to keep the code visible without scrolling....

Comment: I was hoping you would comment on above edit to original question seeking understanding.  One more thing I also don't get about your answer: the key `<xsl:key name="kMFByFId" match="MothersFatherID"  use="../FathersID"/>`.  What is `../FathersID`. I thought `..` refers to a parent but I can't see how to be at a lower node to where FathersID is found, as 'Child' node where FathersID is found is already the lowest node?

Comment: @user1840734, `../FathersID` when evaluated with context node `MothersFatherID`, selects all `FathersID` siblings (we know that this would be just one element) of the context node. To spell this in detail: 1) `..` changes the context node to the parent. 2) `../FathersID` means *select all `FathersID` children of my parent* -- and this causes all `FathersID` siblings to be selected. I could have just written: `preceding-sibling::FathersID` but I was not sure that a `FathersID` would always precede a `MothersFatherID`.

Comment: @user1840734, I have updated the answer and answered your new questions.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should do what you're looking to do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:key name="kFathersChildren" match="Child" 
           use="concat(FathersID, ' - ', MothersFatherID)"/>
  <xsl:key name="kChildByFatherId" match="Child" use="FathersID"/>
  <xsl:key name="kMothersFatherById" match="MothersFather" use="ID" />

  <xsl:template match="text() | Children | MothersFathers" />

  <xsl:template match="Father">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#10;FATHER: ID=', ID)" />

    <xsl:apply-templates 
      select="key('kMothersFatherById', 
                 key('kChildByFatherId', ID)
                   [generate-id() = 
                     generate-id(
                       key('kFathersChildren', 
                          concat(FathersID, ' - ', MothersFatherID)
                           )[1])
                   ]/MothersFatherID)">
      <xsl:sort select="ID" data-type="number" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="MothersFather">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#10;      IN MothersFather template... ID=', ID)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

```
FATHER: ID=100
      IN MothersFather template... ID=200
      IN MothersFather template... ID=201
      IN MothersFather template... ID=202
FATHER: ID=101
      IN MothersFather template... ID=201
```

Comment: Thanks JLRishie, I've gone with Dimitre's answer but they are both very similar. Cheers.