# Counting figures in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to write some xslt that will enumerate all images in my xml(s!)

i am using a key for this so that i can reference the images later in the content,
my problem here is i cant figure out how to get a consistent value.
Meaning:
the xml has references to multiple other documents which i am loading using document(),
whenever i "enter" a new document the key is reset, so in documents that have 2 images i get a count of two, in others one

so you can imagine

root doc:

```
<root>
  <chapter href="chapters/doc1.xml"/>
  <chapter href="chapters/doc2.xml"/>
</root>
```

doc1.xml

```
<root>
  <image id="a"/>
  <image id="b"/>
</root>
```

doc2.xml

```
<root>
  <image id="f"/>
</root>
```

i found a old thread here on stackoverflow that i think goes kind of in my direction: [XSLT: create 'key' across multiple documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762995/xslt-create-key-across-multiple-documents#) 
but i was not able to make it work.

what is currently working:
i have defined a key

```
<xsl:key name="image" match="image" use="@id"/>
```

that im using later like this

```
 key value for image:<xsl:value-of select="count(key('image', @id)/preceding::image) + 1"/>
```

this always produces the mentioned result (for doc1 i get "`key value for image:1 key value for image:2`" bur for doc2 i get "`key value for image:1`" again and here i would expect a 3)

trying to adapt to the linked post i have tried to load all documents using collection and at create a new key hoping it would yield me at least all images for the start

```
<xsl:key name="images" match="image" use="all"/>
```

```
 <xsl:variable name="location"><xsl:value-of select="$xml-base"/>/chapters?select=*.xml;recurse=yes</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="documents">
  <xsl:value-of select="collection($location)"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="collection($location)">
  <xsl:message>
    <xsl:value-of select="./count(key('figure','all'))"/>
  </xsl:message>
</xsl:for-each>
```

and that always gives me 0
i am not even sure if using key is the right approach here

tldr: 
how can i enumerate images in xslt across multiple documents?

*edit as i think it was a bit unclear:
i have multiple xml inputs imported by a root xml,
all of them can contain images
i have a final output file that needs to enumerate all images continiously and be able to reference them

Comment: "*but i was not able to make it work.*" Show your attempt so that we can fix it, instead of starting from scratch.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks for taking the time i added some context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That last document has a single `image` element, therefore that `image` doesn't have any `preceding::image`.

It is also not clear why you need a key at all if you want to count `image` elements, `count(//image)` for a single document or `count(document(/root/chapter/@href)//image)` for using the `document` function on that first sample or `count(collection('chapters?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')//image)` for the XSLT 2/3 and Saxon 9 specific `collection()` call should do.

`<xsl:key name="images" match="image" use="all"/>` is meaningless unless any `image` element has child elements named `all`.

Dealing with severals documents is possible but requires some extra effort. If you need general processing and can't push all elements together through a template to exploit `position()` but somehow need to index all those `image` elements then perhaps doing `<xsl:variable name="images" select="document(/root/chapter/@href)//image"/>` and `<xsl:variable name="image-ids" select="for $img in $images return generate-id($img)"/>` and then simply using `<xsl:value-of select="index-of($image-ids, generate-id())"/>` in any `xsl:template match="image"` should work.

The `for $img in $images return generate-id($img)` can be written more compactly in XSLT 3 as `$images ! generate-id()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i think my question was not clear enough - sorry for that -  i do not expect 3, i need three because as i said, i need to enumerate all images in a final single output file
it might be the key is the wrong thing for that, but that also was part of my question
to come to your proposal of using ```count(document(/root/chapter/@href)//image)```i would have to count all images in every sub chapter and find a way to re enumerate because i want it continiously counting up, does that make my problem a bit clearer

Comment: @MatthiasG, can you live with pushing `document(/root/chapter/@href)//image` through a template doing `<xsl:template match="image"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/>...</xsl:template>` using `<xsl:apply-templates select="document(/root/chapter/@href)//image"/>`? If you push them all together, as shown, the inside the template the `position()` function should give the "index" of the currently processed `image` element in the whole sequence of `image` elements selected by `document(/root/chapter/@href)//image`.

Comment: i tried that in the sample document i provided and im happy that it works, i now do have the problem to apply all other rules to the rest of the content, there are other elements sometimes before sometimes after sometimes enclosing those images  and i am not sure how to proceed with these now... is this a concept that i am misunderstanding? because what i did is create templates matching the elements and inside of the templates most of the time i just use <apply-templates/> is there a way to use your approach with these other elements?

Comment: @MatthiasG, if the number is needed while you process all nodes then you need a different approach, see whether the suggestion in the edit helps.